# Solution verification: a continuous function in an open interval $(a,b)$ with finite limits of $f(a^+)$ and $f(b^-)$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Solution verification: a continuous function in an open interval $(a,b)$ with finite limits of $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow b^-}f(x)$ is bounded

Proof:  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow b^-}f(x)$ exist and are finite. Lets denote them: $L_1$ and $L_2$ respectively. So since $f$ is continuous there are $c,d \in (a,b)$ so that $f(c)=L_1$ and $f(d)=L_2$. So since $f$ is continuous in $[c,d] \subseteq (a,b)$, then it's bounded there, so it must also be bounded in $(a,b)$.

Is this solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not: on an *open* interval, limits are not necessarily attained. But you can extend $f$ to a continuous function $\tilde f$ on the closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$. Now it's a theorem that a continuous function on a closed bounded interval is bounded on that interval (and actually attains a maximum and a minimum) (Weierstrass's boundedness theorem). So $f$, which is the *restriction* of $\tilde f$ to the open interval $]a,b[$, is also bounded (but doesn't necessarily attains a maximum nor a minimum on  $]a,b[$.

Comment: It is given that the limits exist and are finite. And I don't know whether $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, so I can't use the Weierstrass'es theorem here.

Comment: $f$ is continuous on the open interval $]a,b[$ and it *can* be extended to a *continuous* $\tilde f$ on $[a,b]$: you just have to define $\tilde f(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and similarly for $\tilde f(b)$.

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks.